# (US, alternative international) keyboard in tty console

Tags: keyboard-layout, tty

Is it possible to use the US,alternative-international keyboard in my TTY console?

If not, is there a way I can use it in vim inside the TTY console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change layout and maintain changes after system reboot, run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

And then run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the layout with `console-data`.
If not installed use `sudo apt-get install console-data` to install it.
Then use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data` to change the layout.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! You have to choose to show all keymaps and choose the keymap: ( pc / qwerty / us American / standard / us international)

Comment: But the changes get canceled after system reboot. I found another way using keyboard-configuration (but it doesn't have the ç without using AltGr, but neither does my keyboard layout in unity)